# User meta to post

Tags: user-meta

I created a field (not acf) in the user profile. The field is called “genere”, and I have another field in the post created with ACF called the same "genere", but it is invoked in my function by the `$field_key`.

I can now pass this `usermeta` field to the author’s post to a `acf_field` with `acf_update_field` but only after I click on “Update User” in *edit-user.php*.

There is only one post per author, at most two by mistake. So when I click on "Update User" in user-edit.php, the author post also updates. I would like every `usermeta` of "genere" field value to pass automatically to the author's post **already created.**

Another my previous function creates the author's post when this user is created. When I update the user, his post already exists. So for future author's posts I do not need solutions because by updating the profile, the field value passes well and works. **The problem is only for the posts already created** (in my theme by default each user has a post).

There are 2500 users and I would need to pass the value to the post without manually updating the *user-edit.php* page.

This is my code in the file *functions.php*

```
function save_acf($user_id)
  {
    global $post;
    $args = array(
   'author' =>  $user_id,
    );
   $myposts = get_posts( $args );
   foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
    setup_postdata($post);
    $numero = $post->ID;
   endforeach; 

 if( isset($_POST['genere']) ) { 
    $post_id = $numero ;
    $field_key = "field_5941b968b5ad6";
    $value =  sanitize_text_field( $_POST['genere'] ) ;
  update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );}
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'save_acf');
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_acf' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_acf' );
```

- Probably the actions `user_register` and `personal_options_update` are no influence

### EDIT

With hwl's suggestions in his answer I found this work solution.

Bulk action > get user by usermeta from MySql > get the id of users with foreach > update postmeta with foreach post

```
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-post', 'register_my_bulk_actions2' );
 function register_my_bulk_actions2($post_ids) {
    global $wpdb;
      $users = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE meta_key = 'genere'AND meta_value = 'Maschio' " );
    foreach ( $users as $a ) {
        $author_ids[] = $a->user_id;
    }

   $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ,  'author__in' =>  $author_ids, );
   $myposts = get_posts( $args );
   foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
     $numero = $post->ID;
     update_post_meta( $numero, 'genere', 'Maschio' );
   endforeach; 
  }
```

Best regards

Comment: Can you clarify the problem you're trying to solve? You have a user_meta of `genere`, and you want to save the value of that in the `acf_field` of all of the posts by that author, for every author? For current posts and/or for new posts as they are added?

Comment: Dear hwl thank you for you attention again. I have updated the question with a bit more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at leasts one approach to this would be the following process:
- get all posts by authors
- foreach post: 
  - get the author `user_meta` `genere`
  - update the `post_meta` with that value

I have **not** tested any of the code below, so I wouldn't copy/paste. 
But hopefully reading through it will get you in the right direction.

I've linked to info on used functions/classes at end.

---

```
function update_post_meta_with_user_meta() {
         //setup arguments to only get users with author role
         $user_args = array( 
                          'role' => 'author', 
                          );
        $authors   =  get_users( $user_args );
        //the below foreach could be replaced by adding something like:
        // fields => array( 'ID' ) to $user_args

       //instead I am just going through returned array of WP_User objects 
       //  and putting IDs into array
        foreach ( $authors as $a ) {
            $author_ids[] = $a->ID;
        }

       //setup post query arguments to only give us posts with authors in author_id array
       //which means only posts that have an author with the WP role of author
       // should exclude Editors, Admins, etc. that maybe have authored posts
        $post_args = array(
                          'author__in' => $author_ids,
                        );

        //a new WP_Query with these args   
        $post_query   = new WP_Query( $post_args ) ) );

        //make sure we have posts returned
        if ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {

            //loop
            while ( $post_query->have_posts() ) {

                $post_query->the_post();

                //set $post_id variable to current post
                $post_id = get_the_id();

                //get author meta for author of current post
                $author_genere = get_the_author_meta('genere');

                //update the meta of the current post (by ID) 
                //  with the value of its author's user meta key
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'genere', $author_genere );
            }

            //reset the postdata
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

    }
    //hook the above to init
    add_action( 'init', 'update_post_meta_with_user_meta' );
```

---

- [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)
- [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
- [`get_the_id()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/)
- [`get_the_author_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/)
- [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)
- [`init` hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init)

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work...

Comment: Have tried what?

Comment: All your functions, coping and pasting. There was a syntax error here:  $post_query   = new WP_Query( $post_args ) ) );
I'll check later your code. Anyway... thank you. I hope soon to found a solution :)

Comment: This is a walk through not complete code. As I stated, _I wouldn't copy/paste. But hopefully reading through it will get you in the right direction_.  All those links give greater detail to the Wordpress specific pieces. Avoid asking for completed code, as moderators could close your question as off topic under _asking to work for me for free_. If you don't follow some part of the logic, do ask about that. There could easily be a more efficient way. :)

Comment: Yes you are right. But I didn't have time and I made quick tests. Now I got inspiration from your code but I have not found the solution yet. Maybe the solution by MySql is the simplest. Anyway, thank you very much,